# Will this cookie track what visitors do after they have clicked on a rep url? The pages they go to, until they leave the site?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

As I have no idea of code, html or the programs I am using, I would like to know if this cookie will work the way I want it to.

I would like to know what pages the user visits in the session after he/she has arrived to the website via the url containing: **repid**.

I have a custom html tag that I have set up in Google tag Manager and the code is:

```
    <script>
    var cookieName = "RepUrl"; 
    var cookieValue = "true";
    setPersistentCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, 365); // set for 1 year
    </script>
```

The Trigger Type is Page View, Some Page Views, Page Url, Contains, **repid**

I then went to google analytics and created a Custom Dimension called Rep Url the scope was Session.

After this I go back to google tag manager and create a variable called: Cookie-Page..., Variable type: 1st party cookie and linked to the cookieName: **RepUrl** (as in the above code).

Then I make another tag, this time it is a google analytics tag type, track type: page view. I then enable overriding settings in this tag and enter my google analytics id UA-xxxxxxxxx-x . I go to more settings, custom dimensions and enter the index number of the custom dimension I created in google analytics and in the dimension value, I enter the variable I created in tag manager called: Cookie-Page...

After all this I then went to customization, custom reports in analytics created one for the custom dimension **(Rep Url)** with added filters: Sessions, Avg. Session duration, Entrances/Pageviews, Pages/Session, Users.

I would like to know from start to end if this cookie will work the way I would like it to. All help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The GTM/GA setup will work, but you might not get the results that you were hoping for in the custom reports.

One reason is that you're setting the cookie once the user, enters the site and arrives at the page with RepUrl, but by that time, the hit for the page view would already be sent to GA thus not capturing into the custom dimension until subsequent hits. This would throw off the sessions, entrances metric in the custom reports.

You could consider looking into creating a custom segment that isolates sessions with the parameter "repurl". This would work if repurl would always be how the user enters the site/starts the session.

Another solution would be to abandon the javascript for setting the cookie, but instead, user the URL variable in GTM and capture the RepUrl parameter that way and set it on pageview.

Comment: Hi XTOTHEL, Thankyou for the reply. The repurl that triggers with the repid is not always how users would enter the site but it is the main way that I want to track. So would creating this custom segment still work?

Comment: I have gone to my custom report added a custom segment, clicked advanced conditions and clicked on my custom dimension Rep Url then said contains and true. Are these the correct steps?